# Trying to "select all" and dragging whole document - but some lines do not move

Tags: inkscape, grids

In Inkscape I am editing [an SVG file](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q8/MyDecoder2/assets/game_board.svg) (please click the **Raw** button to download; copyright [CC-BY-SA by Denelson83](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg#mediaviewer/File:Blank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg)).

I have defined a grid of 15 x 15 for the whole document and toggled the **Snap bounding box corners** button on the right.

I am trying to move everything to the left and to the top - so that the drawn black grid lines match the grid of my Inkscape document.

So I **Edit - Select All in All Layers** and drag with the mouse:

[image: Inkscape 1]

Unfortunately, the black lines do not move for some reason - please help:

[image: Inkscape 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have any layers locked. That could prevent items from being moved.

Answer (score 2):

Nico Bach is right! First unlock the layer "grid" in the layer dialog (shift-ctrl-L). After that, make sure to use "snap nodes, paths and handles" instead of "snap bounding boxes". Also select "snap cusp nodes", and grab your selection close to an intersection of the black lines.

When selecting everything the bounding box would also include the "A" and the "1", and therefore after snapping the bounding box, your black lines would not get aligned to the document's grid. The bounding box corner would, but that's quite useless in this case.

Comment: Your suggestion to enable "Snap nodes or handles" made my editing job much easier :-)